How to find each word in a 2D array from a specific ch
I'm new to Java and I'm trying to work this question out:
Write another method in the class (a suitable name for this method would be findChar). This method should take a char and a 2 dimensional array of String objects as parameters. The purpose of the method is to display every word in the array which contains the character. (The search should be completely case insensitive.)
This is what I have got so far. I just can't work out how to do the next part:
public static void findChar(String[][] arr, char ch) {
    ch lowerCh = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    for (String[] row : arr) {
        for (String word : row) {
            //pseudocode   
            if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCh) is in array) 
            print(word)
        }
    }


You're close. Refer to javadoc for method indexOf (in class String). If lowerCh is not in word then indexOf returns -1 (minus one)

If the indexOf() method can't find the desired character then -1 is returned, so...if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCh) >= 0) {.

ch lowerCh  will not compile since ch is not a valid type : it should be char lowerCh; also is in array is probably meant to be "is found" or similar, basically != -1 (or >= 0  as commented above) since indexOf() will return -1 if the character is not found

Using java 8:
public static void findChar(String[][] arr, char ch) {
char lowerCh = Character.toLowerCase(ch);

// Create a stream from the 2D array
Arrays.stream(arr)
      // Flatten the 2D array into a single stream of strings
      .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
      // Filter the words that contain the lowercase character
      .filter(word -> word.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).indexOf(lowerCh) != -1)
      // Print each matching word
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}


I changed your code and tested it worked
  public static void findChar(String[][] array, char ch) {
        char lowerCh = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        for (String[] strings : array) {
            for (String word : strings) {
                if (word.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).indexOf(lowerCh) != -1) {
                    print(word);
                }
            }
        }
    }

